# How to do sftp via password

Tags: sftp, lftp

I am trying to transfer files via sftp with password mode but getting below message
 content of file `put-script`

```
 open sftp://user:password@host  
 get /tmp/testftp.txt  
 exit
```

Output:

```
 $ lftp -f put-script  
/tmp/testftp.txt' at 0 [Delaying before reconnect: 29]
```

Please help

Answer (score 2):

That script *might* be made to work (but the manual page does not hint that it would accept the user and password in that manner).

What works for me is to factor out the user/password like this:

```
lftp -u user,password -e "command"
```

But I am using *that* with a private key, by setting options at the beginning of the command to use a given *mykeyfile* (which one could use in a script):

```
set ftp:ssl-allow yes
set ssl:key-file mykeyfile
set ftp:ssl-force true;
```

since private keys are generally preferable.  For that case, `lftp` ignores the given password on the command (but it must be given, to appease its command-parser).

Comment: I did   lftp -u User,password  
lftp batch@:~> set ftp:ssl-force true;  
lftp batch@:~> get /tmp/testftp.txt  
But I got `/tmp/testftp.txt' at 0
And this remained on the screen for a long time (Until I did ctrl+C)

Comment: If you have not put your public key on the server, it will hang.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the value of requiredpasswordauthentication to "Yes" in sshd configuration and then rebooted the service.
Now I am able to do sftp via password.